# Can we use one devexpress toolkit for more than one developers

Tags: devexpress

I have to purchase devexpress asp.net web controls for my application. we have two developers. can we use one license for both developers?

Answer (score 0):

Read devexpress product licensing here:

[Devexpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/support/eulas/)

With regards to your question.

**Is your license on a per-developer basis? Does each developer using your products require a license?**

Yes. Each developer that uses our products must have their own license. We don't license per machine, per server, or demand any royalties or run-time fees. For more information, refer to our End-User License Agreement. If you have a testing team and they need to compile the application, then those testers will also each need a license. Testers who just test the completed, compiled application (that is, use it much as an end-user does) do not need a license.

But :) **Can I install the product on two computers (I'm running a desktop in the office and have a laptop at home)?**

Absolutely.

Comment: I read this one, but I don't really understand how it works. I have more than two developers working on the same application. So Do I need to purchase license for each machine?

Comment: I have been sharing the same license across my whole team, you will not experience any issues, so, feel free to use just one.

Comment: appreciate if you accept and vote up the answer if it helps, thanks !